# Using 7zip to archive file by year

Tags: file, batch-file, 7zip

I have a batch script that runs 7zip and allows me to zip all the files in one folder. I only want to zip files that have a Date Modified of 2010 or another date of my choosing. I want to delete the files after I get them archived into a zip folder. This is my logic.
Find files that are from 2012 and archive those files into a folder called 2012. Zip the folder and delete the files. 0

This is what I have so far.

```
@ECHO OFF

REM This sets name of the zip file
Set choice=
set /p choice=What is the year of the files?
PAUSE

REM This sets the path of the file
Set path=
set /p path=What is the path of the files on C:\'path'\?

REM Use 7Zip to Zip files in folder c:\path and place the zip archive in C:\path

ECHO.
ECHO Zipping all files in C:\%path% and moving archive to c:\%path%
ECHO.
PAUSE

C:\7z a -tzip "C:\%path%\%choice%.zip" "C:\%path%\*.*" -mx5
ECHO.
PAUSE

ECHO Would you like to Delete the files in orginal folder?
DEL "C:\%path%\*.*"
PAUSE

ECHO File is now zipped
```

Comment: Danger Will Robinson, danger.  The `set /p path=` line you have there will make Windows forget where to find some of its executables, at least until it's rebooted.  Best not to recycle variables that already have another purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Seems pretty straight forward.  By the way, I'm not familiar with 7zip's command-line switches.  I'm taking it for granted that you already have the syntax of 7z.exe the way it needs to be.

```
@echo off

set 7z=C:\7z.exe
if not exist %7z% set /p 7z="Path to 7-zip executable? "

set /p year="What year do you wish to archive? "

set /p dir="What is the path of the files you wish to archive? "

mkdir "%year%"

rem output of dir is date time am/pm size filename
rem filename = 5th + additional tokens
for /f "tokens=5*" %%I in ('dir "%dir%" ^| find "/%year%"') do move "%dir%\%%I %%J" "%year%"

%7z% a -tzip "%dir%\%year%.zip" "%year%" -mx5

set /p I="I'm about to delete the %year% folder.  Hit Ctrl-C if this is a bad idea, or hit Enter to continue."
rmdir /q /s "%year%"

echo Done.  w00p.
```

I think what you were missing is the `for` loop.  As I've written it, it performs a directory listing, disregards anything not matching the year as the user enters it, then moves token 5* to the %year% directory for zipping.

Comment: That works for me. I changed the code up a lot, but I just want to thank you for the find /year command.

Comment: Old, but worth mentioning that `7z` is a bad variable name, since `%7` evaluates before `%7z%` in a batch script